# Applying index numbering within map for specific set of elements in the object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have implemented versioning which works but think its no the best way to it. I am versioning documents named Agreement.pdf as Agreement_v1.pdf,Agreement_v2.pdf and so on based on the date sorting.

The investigationsCase.state.documents object contains the following values before the applying the version logic. As you can see in the logic written in the component, I have initialised variable

```
   let i: number = 0;
```

I am then incrementing this variable i++ in the map function. I tried to use the index in the map function which applies index to all documents including   Agreement.pdf which is not correct as the Agreement
documents would contain incorrect version numbers. How do I solve this issue.

```
{
fullPath: "onboarding-documents/null/a3c9cbc5-5f16-43cb-89e8-49fb8985d2e6/Capture.PNG-85-2021741937"
isActive: true
name: "Capture.PNG"
type: "Identification"
uploadedBy: "102752499038291113813"
uploadedOnDate: "2021-08-05T18:37:56.784+00:00"
},
{
fullPath: "onboarding-documents/test-1/a3c9cbc5-5f16-43cb-89e8-49fb8985d2e6/Agreement_637637674187949978.pdf"
isActive: true
name: "Agreement.pdf"
type: "Agreement"
uploadedBy: null
uploadedOnDate: "2021-08-05T13:39:31.1832277+00:00"
},
{
fullPath: "onboarding-documents/test-1/a3c9cbc5-5f16-43cb-89e8-49fb8985d2e6/Agreement_637637673233897410.pdf"
isActive: true
name: "Agreement.pdf"
type: "Agreement"
uploadedBy: null
uploadedOnDate: "2021-08-05T13:37:00.7386213+00:00"
}
```

Component

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    let i: number = 0;

    if (this.readOnly) {
      this.columnsToDisplay = ['category', 'filename', 'uploadedOnDate'];
    } else {
      this.columnsToDisplay = ['category', 'filename', 'uploadedOnDate', 'action', 'delete'];
    }
    
    const investigationDocuments = this.caseChange$
      .pipe(
        map(investigationsCase => {
          this.configureSendNewAgreement(investigationsCase.state.documents);
          return investigationsCase.state.documents
            ? investigationsCase.state.documents
              .sort((x, y) => +new Date(x.uploadedOnDate) - +new Date(y.uploadedOnDate))
              .map(d=> d.type=== TypeOfDocument.Agreement ? ({...d, name: d.name= 'Agreement_v' + (i++) + '.pdf' } ) : d ).filter(doc => doc.isActive === true) : []}),
        tap(a => {
          a.filter(d => d.type !== TypeOfDocument.Identification).forEach(b => b.isEditable = true);
        }),
      );

}
```

Comment: try a tap to increment the i before the map?

Comment: Agree with first comment to do a `console.log` check. Additionally, I would strongly recommend declaring `i` inside the `map()` operator of your observable pipe. You should rarely ever have observables dependent on external variables when managing state. Right now, `i` won't reset to zero when `caseChange$` emits a new set of documents.

Comment: At the moment if I include i as an index param in the map, it indexes all the documents including non-agreement documents which isn't correct. I need to index documents that are of type Agreement only.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't add code to comments, I'll reply here.

You should define the counter within the observable itself. I mentioned in my comment to define the counter inside the map operator (not the array map). This way, you can increment the counter when the document is an agreement. Here's how I would execute your code:

```
this.columnsToDisplay = ["category", "filename", "uploadedOnDate"];
if (!this.readOnly) this.columnsToDisplay.push(["action", "delete"]);

const investigatoinDocuments$ = this.caseChange$.pipe(
  tap(investigationsCase =>
    this.configureSendNewAgreement(investigationsCase.state.documents)
  ),
  map(investigationsCase=>!!investigationsCase.state.documents ? investigationsCase.state.documents : []),
  map(documents=>{
    let i = 0;
    return documents
    .filter(document=>document.isActive)
    .sort((x, y) => +new Date(x.uploadedOnDate) - +new Date(y.uploadedOnDate))
    .map(document=>{
      if(document.type === TypeOfDocument.Agreement) document.name = `Agreement_v${++i}.pdf`;
      if(document.type !== TypeOfDocument.Identification) document.isEditable = true;
      return document
    })
  })
);
```

Now, each time `caseChange$` emits a new set of documents, the counter will reset to `0`.

Comment: Thanks @digclo. I am just getting a compilation error in the last IF statement This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'TypeOfDocument.Agreement' and 'TypeOfDocument.Identification' have no overlap

Comment: Sorry, had a rogue open bracket after the first if statement. This caused typescript to think the second conditional was inside the first. I updated my example which should fix that error.